VBA: Number the cells in a range in sequential order up to a maximum value
So I want to number the cells in the following range:
R1 = Union(Range("A2:A24"), Range("E2:E24"), Range("I2:I17")).Select
I aim to assign numbers to them starting from 1 and going up to a set maximum value.
Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C6:C" & L1), "2")
If Var is less than the number of cells in the range, I want the remaining cells to be empty.

What do you mean by "value of Var is inferior to the number of cells in the range I want the rest of the cells blank"? What range are you talking about? The one where you try counting "2"? If so, why did you (wrongly) try define R1 range? What value has L1? Is it > 62?

How do I ask a good question?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You could use the following template
    Sub NumberCellsInRange()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim maxNumber As Long
        Dim currentNumber As Long
        Dim totalCells As Long
    
        ' Define the range you want to work with
        Set rng = Range("A1:b5") ' Change this to your desired range
        ' In your case, you don't need to select it
        ' R1 = Union(Range("A2:A24"), Range("E2:E24"), Range("I2:I17"))
        
        ' How many cells to number
        maxNumber = 5
        ' In your case, why var? It's a number
        ' Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C6:C" & L1), "2")
        
        ' Initialize the counter
        currentNumber = 1
        totalCells = rng.Count
    
        ' Loop through each cell in the range
        For Each cell In rng
            If currentNumber <= maxNumber Then
                cell.Value = currentNumber
                currentNumber = currentNumber + 1
            Else
                cell.Value = "" ' Leave remaining cells empty
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub

more compact version:
Sub NumberCellsInRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentNumber As Long
    
    ' Define the range and the maximum number of cells to number
    Set rng = Range("A1:B5") ' Modify this to your desired range
    Const maxNumber As Long = 8 ' Maximum numbers to fill

    i = 1
    Set cell = rng.Cells(i)
    Do Until i > maxNumber Or cell Is Nothing
        cell.Value = i
        i = i + 1
        Set cell = rng.Cells(i)
    Loop
End Sub


Populate an Integer Sequence

Sub PopulateIntegerSequence()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C6"
    Const SRC_CRITERIA As String = "2"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A2:A24,E2:E24,I2:I17"
    Const START_INTEGER As Long = 1
    Const DISPLAY_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source: Calculate the number of integers using the required logic
    ' i.e. as many times the criteria string appears in the source range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim sRowsCount As Long, IntegersCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        sRowsCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If sRowsCount < 1 Then
            IntegersCount = 0 ' no source data
        Else
            IntegersCount = Application.CountIf( _
                .Resize(sRowsCount), SRC_CRITERIA)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Destination: Clear existing destination data.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    drg.ClearContents
    
    If IntegersCount = 0 Then GoTo IsDone ' no source data or no matches
    
    ' Destination: Write the integer sequence to the destination range.
    
    Dim CurrentInteger As Long: CurrentInteger = START_INTEGER - 1
    Dim RemainingCount As Long: RemainingCount = IntegersCount
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    
    For Each dcell In drg.Cells
        CurrentInteger = CurrentInteger + 1
        dcell.Value = CurrentInteger
        RemainingCount = RemainingCount - 1
        If RemainingCount = 0 Then Exit For ' ran out of integers
    Next dcell
    
IsDone:
    ' Inform.
    If DISPLAY_MESSAGE Then
        Select Case IntegersCount
            Case 0 ' no source data or no matches
                MsgBox "No integers populated!", vbExclamation
            Case 1
                MsgBox "Populated the integer " & START_INTEGER & ".", _
                    vbInformation
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Populated " & IntegersCount - RemainingCount _
                    & " integers from " & START_INTEGER _
                    & " to " & CurrentInteger & ".", vbInformation
        End Select
    End If

End Sub


I suppose this macro should meet your target:
Option Explicit

Sub asdfasd() ' (L1 as long) to get L1 as a parameter
  Dim L1 As Long ' delete this line if L1 is a parameter
  Dim R1 As Range, Var As Long, rc As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  L1 = 1000 ' simulated value; delete this line to use real L1 value  
  Set R1 = Union(Range("A2:A24"), Range("E2:E24"), Range("I2:I17"))
  Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C6:C" & L1), "2")
  Var = 50 ' simulated value; delete this line to use Var gotten line above
  rc = R1.Cells.Count
  If Var < rc Then rc = Var
  j = 1
  For k = 1 To R1.Areas.Count
    With R1.Areas(k)
      For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
        .Cells(i) = IIf(j <= Var, j, "")
        j = j + 1
      Next
    End With
  Next
End Sub


